# Importing Airflow Plugin

Tags: google-bigquery, salesforce, airflow

I am currently trying to push data from Salesforce to BigQuery using Airflow. I am new to airflow and currently I'm following this link:

https://github.com/TheF1rstPancake/airflow-salesforce

When I try to import the plugin 
`from airflow.operators import SalesforceToFileOperator`,

I get the error message stating `ImportError: cannot import name 'SalesforceToFileOperator'`

How do I import this plugin on Airflow?

Current Directory Structure

DAGS

```
  salesforce_bg.py
```

plugins

```
airflow-salesforce

      __init__.py
      hooks
      operators
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the official Airflow documentation: [here](https://airflow.apache.org/plugins.html)

> The python modules in the plugins folder get imported, and hooks, operators, sensors, macros, executors and web views get integrated to Airflow’s main collections and become available for use.

So, you only need to place `salesforce_bg.py` into the `/plugins` folder of your Airflow server.

Comment: where should i move the other folders?

Comment: You only really need 2 things:  custom operators going into `/plugins` as shown above and point your airflow `dags_folder` entry inside airflow.cfg to the folders where your DAGS are.